# Visual Studio Code C Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

it's my first day trying to learn C. I am using Visual Studio and I when I   run the code here is the message I receive

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.221 seconds
```

And here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

I tried this one as well and it's the same message

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Comment: Are you on an ARM architecture? How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file before hitting the build button? That's one surprisingly common cause of that error. Also note that visual-studio-code and visual-studio are different IDEs. Tag only the relevant one (the former in this case it sounds like).

Comment: Yes, that was It, I haven't saved it. I used Jupiter before and there is no need to save it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I.
First, you have to understand that you don't include the same library twice like you did in the second code block line 1 and 3 (#include <stdio.h>).
Second, Just the 'void' function not return value.
So, if you set your main function as int you must return value to the operation system. (The system have to know that your program done.)

About your problem, if you using Windows - check to opening project definitions, make sure that you open project in -> Console Application. Be sure that you working with C compiler (In some Visual Studio versions you need to change the end of file from filename.cpp to filename.c)

If you using Mac, I know the silicon M1 Processors don't have C compiler in Visual Studio so you need to write in XCODE or VScode (they have compiler).
Try to check and if you still need help reply my answer and add some photos\more info.
I'll try to help :)